# Maximum compatible kernel version

Tags: 16.04, kernel, updates, lts

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Since I was facing the [suspend bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761820/suspend-not-working-on-ubuntu-16-04-for-dell-3537), I installed a newer kernel as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/763110/173003).

Even though the above mentioned link recommends to install kernel *v4.4.8-wily*, there seems to be even newer versions available [here](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/), such as *v4.4.9-xenial*, *v4.4.10-xenial*, *v4.6-yakkety* etc.

What is the maximum version that is compatible with Ubuntu 16.04 that will not introduce more bugs?

Also, just curious to know, what is the significance of the names after the hyphen `-`? How is *v4.4.8-**wily*** compatible with Xenial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I would recommend going with last one prepared for same release (16.04 Xenial), current:

  http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.4.13-xenial/
- Only if you are looking to submit a bug report against kernel, then you should try the bleeding edge upload (including `rc`) to include results in the report, current:

  http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.7-rc2-yakkety/

We can't say compatible/or not (for example `v4.4.8-wily` with Xenial). You can almost run any kernel on any release when when they have same major release (`4`) and somehow close minor release (`4`/`7`). The only difference is that `*-xenial` kernel releases had passed some QA/Tests prepared for same Xenial release, no more no less.

Answer (score 1):

This might help: http://people.canonical.com/~kernel/info/kernel-version-map.html

Currently the lastest out of the box ubuntu 16.04 kernels are based on 4.4.8

Ex. 4.4.0-22.39 Ubuntu-4.4.0-22.39  4.4.8

You'd likely best be served by sticking with the kernel that comes with Ubuntu.   If the AMD drivers are an issue I've heard others recommend sticking with 14.04